# How to block claim68639680.copyrightclaims.org in Google Analytics

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, spam-prevention, referrer-spam

Does anyone have an effective way of blocking the claim68639680.copyrightclaims.org bot from accessing my WordPress website.

According to Google Analytics they are constantly spamming my site.

I've tried installing a WordPress plugin that is supposed to block them, but that didn't work.

I also tried blocking them via a Filter in Google Analytics according to the below instructions, but that didn't work either. According to Analytics they are still accessing the site at least 5 times a day.

http://botcrawl.com/stop-copyrightclaims-org-referral-spam-in-google-analytics/

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: This is off topic as it's not related to coding. It's better suited for the Webmasters forum. That said, one possibility to look into is to create "include" filters that permit only traffic from whitelisted hostnames.

Comment: Well I've now tried everything... The WordPress plugins, applying filters inside Google Analytics, and modifying the .htaccess file. Nothing is working to block them. In fact, now I have 3 different places spamming me...so I'm getting like 100 fake visits a day now.

Answer (score 0):

You can block via .htaccess however they simply need to rotate through different (even by just a single char) to defeat this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).copyrightclaims.org [NC]
RewriteRule - [F]
```

This should take care of any subdomain of copyrightclaims.org

Answer (score 0):

Copyrightclaims.org is yet another ghost referral spam that modifies Google Analytics statistical data and decreases the value of it. I myself faced this problem and after a research find something really useful. These guys provide several methods to deal with this spam and applying them approved to be effective. Add analytics spam filter, use .htaccess file to block it from your server or use WordPress plugins. All these methods have detailed description [here](http://sensorstechforum.com/get-rid-of-copyrightclaims-org-referral-spam-in-google-analytics/).

There are further more useful methods for eliminating all hits from bots and spiders in Google Analytics. They are: enable bot filtering from the admin panel, filter specific IP addresses, adding a JavaScript variable for user agents, add a CAPTCHA requirement and require users to validate their emails.